# Stacking Objects With Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

http://www.pureelysium.com/IainSinclair/cardsharp.html

Im writing the media queries for this. Failing miserably.

Basically these are floating, however upon being 300px wide (iphone etc) i want the image to float above the text. IE rightcontent div to go above the left.

Now i tried swapping the float left to float right

Ie

```
.rightcontent {float: left;}
```

as i thought this would swap the order, however its not. And positioning absolute is proving a nightmare. Can anyone offer assistance.

thanks
Kirsty

Comment: Did you try applying a clear:both; when it becomes 300px or smaller?

Comment: oh sugar no! on the divs? in the main CSS?

Comment: or jus tin the media queries?

Comment: When the media query activates try to apply a clear:both on an element right after the image. This should clear everything to the top and the bottom of the image.

Comment: nope it didnt work :(